# In Bradbury's short story, how can a city be built in the shape of the wind?

Tags: short-stories, symbolism, ray-bradbury

“[The Golden Kite, the Silver Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Kite,_the_Silver_Wind)” is a short story by Ray Bradbury, first published in 1953. It tells the tale of two neighboring Chinese cites, ruled by emperors who continually attempt to foil each other by building their city walls into different shapes.

Initially one of the cities has walls in the shape of an orange. The rival city of Kwan-Si then builds their walls in the shape of a pig:

> “They build their wall,” said the Mandarin, “in the shape of a pig! Do
> you see? Our own city wall is built in the shape of an orange. That
> pig will devour us, greedily!”

To avoid the bad luck this will bring, the first city reshaped its walls “into a club which may beat the pig and drive it off!”.

Kwan-Si then reshape their walls like a bonfire to burn the stick, the other city retaliates to move their walls to resemble a lake to put out the fire, and so on. Eventually so much effort is spent in reshaping the walls that the city people can do nothing else:

> Sickness spread in the city like a pack of evil dogs. Shops closed.
> The population, working now steadily for endless months upon the
> changing of the walls, resembled Death himself

Eventually the the emperors realize that the only solution is cooperation.

> “You, Kwan-Si, will make a last rebuilding of your town to resemble
> nothing more nor less than the wind. And we shall build like a golden
> kite. The wind will beautify the kite and carry it to wondrous
> heights. And the kite will break the sameness of the wind’s existence
> and give it purpose and meaning. One without the other is nothing.
> Together, all will be beauty and co-operation and a long and enduring
> life.”

This seems a fairly clear allegory for the Cold War and the arms race. It may be overly literal of me, but I wonder how some of the city wall shapes could be produced. An orange or a lake would be fairly straightforward (just roundish shapes), but a bonfire, a needle, or a net, for example, seem much more difficult. And in the final solution, one of the cities is built in the shape of a kite - which is a reasonably practical shape for a city - but the other must resemble the wind.

How can a city be built in the shape of the wind?